# sending files via POST with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, post

I have a problem sending data via POST in angular, 
my data include 2 files and some text field, 
the problem is that the service doesn't receives any data.

this is my code:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="file"]' );

Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input ){
    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ){
    if(this.id == "zipToUpload")
            $scope.zipToUpload = this.files[0];
        else
            $scope.imgToUpload = this.files[1];
    });
}); 

$scope.submit = function(){
    var getInput = {nome: $scope.app_name, zipToUpload: $scope.zipToUpload, imgToUpload: $scope.imgToUpload, url: $scope.app_url,
        secure: $scope.checkbox_pass, hide: $scope.checkbox_hide, beta: $scope.checkbox_beta, password: $scope.app_pass, location: "1" };

    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/rest/app/insert_app.php',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        data: getInput
    }

    $http(req)
    .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);        
    });
}
```

Comment: When the AngularJS [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) gets a JavaScript object to POST, it serializes the object into a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) text string. Files are exotic host-based objects that can not be serialized. That is why the server is not receiving the files. There are WebAPI that can work with [exotic File objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). It is necessary to know what formats the server can accept to answer the question of how to send them.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly upload file using model in angular. First you need a directive to bind files to the model.

```
   myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;

              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
     }]);
```

And the input will be like :

```
 <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
```

And the you can send post request using form data

```
$scope.upload = funtion(){
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', $scope.myFile);
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'api/rest/app/insert_app.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    data: fd
   }

$http(req)
.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);        
});
}
```